# Login screen hesitates and login issues with another user after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, login-screen

I installed 12.10 last evening, no issues during install and rebooted OK, however from there have had problems:

1. When login appears for the main account I use, I enter password and screen hesitates, flashes some error I can not catch and goes immediately back to login screen.
2. Login via another user can get in but no disks are mounted and will not allow me to mount any.

Comment: Well i have similar problems, but try installing it again but don't check install third party software and updates

Comment: I did both, did not install any 3rd party on first and second install. Issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Install unity and reboot you computer/laptop. Then click on the footprint next to you user name. It should come up with Ubuntu 2D etc. Click Ubuntu 2D( because ubuntu2D is better). It should work.